# curl php save file perserving modication date in file timestamp

Tags: php, curl, timestamp, filetime

my code works fine but does not perserve filetime/modification date from the server...... i added filetime option to curl but  writing the file still writes the file as the moment it was saved (current date) any suggestions? I am visually impaired so if i made mistake sorry , thank you in advance.

$filename = "image.jpg"
$imgurl = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg"

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $imgurl); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); 
// Getting binary data 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, TRUE);
$image = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

file_put_contents($filename, $image);
```